# understanding a function stringstream

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand this stringstream function `stringstream ss(line);` not quite sure what it's purpose is or what it does.

I'm really new to C++ so I'm sorry if this really simple and stupid. Anything helps thanks!

c++

```
float process(float Beta, std::ifstream & INPUT, float mass, float energy, int Juse = 1, int Jerror = 1, int intype = 1)

{
    float crosscons = 8 * M_PI * mass * mass / energy; //Creates a constant that is used to calculate the cross section

    int dwarf_count = 0;
    int dcol = 0;
    string line;
    string item;
    int header = 0;
    string skip("#"); 
    INPUT.seekg(0, ios::beg); 
    while (getline(INPUT, line))
      
    {
        if (contains(line, skip))
        {
            header++;
        } else {
            break;
        }

    }

    INPUT.seekg(0, ios::beg); // same as above, searching for the INPUT i.e File.
    for (int i = 0; i < header; ++i)
    {
        getline(INPUT, line);

    }
    while (getline(INPUT, line))
    {
        ++dwarf_count;
        if (dwarf_count == 1)
        {
            stringstream ss(line);
            while (ss >> item)
                dcol++; // creates a variable in the while loop, that probably means column
        }

    }
```

Comment: The purists self-pontification of "a constructor *is* a function" notwithstanding, that's not a "function"; its declaration and construction of a [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) object with id `ss`.

Comment: It's a normal variable definition and initialization. It defines the variable `ss` as a [`stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) instance, and initializes it using `line`.

Comment: Look at the output to find out what it does. Use a debugger to find out how it produces the output.